# Iteratively format value inside latex code in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Apologies if this has already been asked, but I couldn't find any information on it. In pyplot, I was wondering if it is possible to format values from a for loop *inside* a piece of latex code? For example, I was hoping to use something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for k in range(len(b)):

    plt.plot(a, b)
    plt.ylabel(r'$\sqrt{| R(a, {}) |}$'.format(k))
    plt.close()
```

which would return the sqrt(| R(a, 1) |), sqrt(| R(a, 1) |) etc as a y label in latex form on each new picture.

Comment: But did you try?

Comment: @DyZ Yes I did try. I'm assuming the error is because the format argument is wrapped in latex code, and latex code uses parentheses for it's own arguments, so the computer is unable to append the format argument properly. I couldn't think of another way to do the above, even after reading the [pyplot tex information](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html), hence the question.

Comment: Python knows nothing about Latex. `{}` is always a format placeholder. However, the real Latex braces must be escaped so that `.format()` would ignore them: `'$\sqrt{{| R(a, {}) |}}$'.format(1)`.

Comment: @DyZ Ok, I see. I suppose my issue then was I wasn't sure how to escape the latex braces. I tried using extra quotations and also \{ \} as you would in a normal latex document, however none of it worked. It's working now. If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for k in range(len(b)):
    plt.plot(a, b)
    plt.ylabel(r'$\sqrt{| R(a, {%s}) |}$' % k)
    plt.show()
```

output

[image]

Comment: `{%s}` may be simply `%`.